# Offset of main content in bottom sheet layout-Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In apps like google map, when bottom sheet expands, the main content wil shrink a little to keep the previous view area at the center. I need the same look.

I've set up the bottomsheetscaffold in the screen, and it works good except for the main content staying still when bottom sheet expands.

Here is my code. Is there any parameter that I can use directly?

```
BottomSheetScaffold(
    sheetContent = {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.height(440.dp)
        ){
                Metermodule()
        }
    },
    sheetPeekHeight = 80.dp,
    sheetElevation = 10.dp,
    content = {
        MapScreen()
    }
)
```

Comment: can you share Metermodule() ? try not to use Modifier.height to the box, because if the content is bigger than that it will be placed differently

Comment: `fun MeterModule() {
    var value by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    Column(
        Modifier.height(400.dp).fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ){ column of some components }`  Here is the code. Thank you.

Comment: Now I use sheetContent = MeterModule() directly, Is this some function that is not provided by the api. Do I need to use State to achieve the function？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually very easy.

1. GoogleMap() provides a parameter for padding the map view. The view zone of the map adjusts itself depends on the padding value. The offset effect can be implemented with padding.
2. The bottomsheet has an animationstate. Read the state of the bottomsheet and do some easy math then it's easy to get the height of the bottomsheet while it is expanding or collapsing.
3. Pass the height value to GoogleMap()'s padding parameter and it works smoothly.

Google Map has more animation which makes the process even smoother. That needs further studies.